# Filter out blanks from Unique Xlookup list

Tags: excel, filter, unique, xlookup

I am trying to rack my brain around adding another formula to the below combination of formulas.

I am getting a unique list that has a matching value in a second column and I am grabbing this list with an offset:

```
=IFERROR(UNIQUE(XLOOKUP(OFFSET(I1,0,0,COUNTA(I:I),1),Ratings_data[rating],Ratings_data[Aggregated Rating])),"")
```

With this formula, I am retrieving a unique list from [Aggregated Ratings] if the [Rating] matches the list in Column I.

There is now a blank value in the data set, so I would like to introduce a filter to this set of formulas to `<>""` however, I can't figure out where in the formula to introduce this.

Would be greatly appreciated if someone could assist me with this.

Edit:

If it helps here is an example of the data in the referenced columns:

| Ratings_data[rating] | Ratings_data[Aggregated Rating] |
| --- | --- |
| Service | Service |
| Drink |  |
| Drink |  |
| Value | Value |
| Service Speed | Service |

Column I:I = a unique list of Ratings_data[rating]

In the above example Drink would come up as a blank value with the above formula and I am trying to filter out these blank cells.

Comment: It's easier for us to understand and help if you could provide some sampl date (see [ask] and [repro]. First idea: use some helper columns for intermediate calculations.

Comment: You should use the `Filter` function around the unique. Unique provides the data, filter you can add the condition to remove the blanks for that column.

Comment: Thanks both. I have edited the original to include a bit more information. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're using a *volatile* `OFFSET` function here: even if the column I values cannot be placed in a `Table`, a dynamic range reference to those values can be created using a non-volatile `INDEX` set-up.

Still, this is not relevant if we use:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(Ratings_data[Aggregated Rating],ISNUMBER(MATCH(Ratings_data[rating],I:I,0))*(Ratings_data[Aggregated Rating]<>"")))`

Comment: You're absolutely right, especially when adding a filter the offset was not necessary anymore as it would filter out the blanks anyways. This is much better and the perfect solution, thanks!!